# FQL: search events from their venue field

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm developing an app that retrieves events via FQL from facebook Pages.
it happens sometimes that the owners of these pages do not create these events from the Page profile, but from their own profile and just link the event to the page as the field Venue (since the pages I'm looking for are public places)

is it possible via FQL or any other mean to get all the events ID that have as venue a specific facebook page ID??

now i can get all the events only if the page owners insert the events via the page profile with the following code:

```
$fql    =   "SELECT eid, creator, name, pic, timezone, start_time, end_time, location, description 
            FROM event WHERE eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN  ($clubsstring) )
            AND start_time > $today
            AND start_time < $nextweek
            ORDER BY start_time asc";

$param  =   array(
    'method'    => 'fql.query',
    'query'     => $fql,
    'callback'  => ''
);

$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
```

thanks
Luca

Comment: How do you get the page events? Can you share your fql query?

Comment: @NitzanTomer i updated the question with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can indeed search based on venues, but that can only be a secondary condition since the venue field is not indexable.

This means that you first **have** to search based on eid (the only indexable field in the `Event` table), and then filter those results based on the venue.

The problem is that the venue field is an array, and the fields in it are not always there, for example one event might have this as venue:

```
"venue": {
    "id": VENUE_ID
}
```

But another will have:

```
"venue": {
    "street": "", 
    "city": "", 
    "state": "", 
    "country": ""
}
```

You should be able to get what you want with something like:

```
SELECT eid, creator, name, pic, timezone, start_time, end_time, location, description 
FROM event
WHERE 
    ((eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN ($clubsstring)))
    OR
    (eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (OWNERS_IDS_STRING)))
    AND
    venue.id IN (VENUE_IDS_STRING))
    AND start_time > $today
    AND start_time < $nextweek
    ORDER BY start_time asc;
```

I haven't tested this query, and you might need to modify it a bit to work, also you can use a different field of venue other than the `id`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right, you are just confirming what i thought about the event FQL table, but maybe it was possible to retrieve the eid's from other tables or other in other ways for all these places that are set as venues for events.

Comment: The solution I provided you does not match your needs? From what I understand from your question is should suffice.

Comment: My bad Nitzan, your solution works perfectly. But it has to work even if the event has been created from other users. You are right though, I did the example only with the owner of the page, sorry.

Comment: You just put a list of users id in the `OWNERS_IDS_STRING` in my example.

Comment: But I don't know those users. The fact is i wan to be able to find events where a specific page is either the creator or the venue

Comment: Oh. So unless you can somehow have a list of events to subset from, then there's no way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

I use this, it´s currently working.

```
{"eventos":"SELECT start_time, end_time, name, eid, pic,venue.id, location, creator, description 
FROM event WHERE eid IN  (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (  SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() LIMIT 150) 
 OR uid = me() AND rsvp_status = 'attending') AND venue.id <>'' 
 AND location <> '' AND location <> '#data'","lugares":"SELECT latitude,longitude  
 FROM place WHERE page_id IN (SELECT venue.id FROM #eventos)"}
```